# Is it ok to ask about "the importance" of applying mathematics in another field

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Some other question was about the importance of knowing mathematics for programmers. I wonder if you think that mathematics will be more or less important for software development in the future. More specifically do you expect a software developer or a programmer in the future to know more or less mathematics? I would believe that most good programmers know some calculus, algebra, discrete mathematics or combinatorics to analyse a problem.

Is the question something that would not get closed and might get an answer? I don't know if it's good for math or better for programmers. I saw similar questions e.g. "Do I have to know mathematics to call myself engineer" while I'm asking what you think the work will look like in the future and if what is traditionally done be a programmer could get divided into two or more roles where I have some very good experienced collaboration with exceptionally good mathematician who did not like to write software program but he could verifiy that a solution theoretically worked and therefore I thought that it was a good team with one programmer and one mathematician while in business such a team is more often one art director/designer and one programmer.

### Question

> Will mathematics be more or less important for the software developers
>   in the far future e.g. 50 yearsw from now, 100 years from now or even further on? I chose to study
>   computer science when I thought that it was important to know more
>   mathematics. I assumed that you had to know much mathematics to be a
>   skilled programmer. Then I read here and there that you might not know
>   much mathematics at all to be a programmer.
>
> Or would you think that roles in teamwork will get more separated and
>   specialized between programmers, architects/designers and and software
>   analysts where programmers might not have to know much mathematics
>   becuse an analyst already analyzed and did the mathematics for a
>   specific program, where the architect/designer was responsible for
>   design and a programmer just translates a problem that was already
>   guaranteed to work and the programmer must not now mathematics and
>   that could be the responsibility of a software analyst?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> do you expect

This has *Closed as primarily opinion-based* written all over it. Better fit for Quora.

Generally, if you'd like to know  about the importance of subject A for subject B, you should ask people doing B rather than people doing A. So... looking at Programmers, I see the question 
[Do you have to be good at math to be a good programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/) with 67 answers. Predictably, closed with the aforementioned reason.